# simple css code, i dont understand

Tags: css

I am looking at some css code and i do not understand this line. The code has a div called shape which contains six other divs each containing an image.

which images does the following code select? As i said the div shape contains six others divs, so why does the code below select only one image?

```
                       #shape > div{
                        }
```

Comment: The selector is for all the direct div childs of element with id shape

Answer (score 5):

Actually `A > B` is a specialization of the more generic `A B`:

- `A B` will apply to any element `B` being somewhere inside an element `A`.
- `A > B` will only apply to elements `B` who are **direct** children of an element `A`.

***Simple example:***

**CSS**

```
.a .b {
    color: red;
}

.a > .b {
    color: blue;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">Hello</div>
    <div class="c">
        <div class="b">World!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can try this example [right here at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgV4X/).

As you can see, the blue color isn't applied to the second instance of an element with the class `b`, because it's no direct child; only a descendant. Otherwise both elements would be blue, due to the second definition (`.a > .b`) following later.

Answer (score 3):

This selects any DIV that is a child of the element with the ID `shape`.

Comment: No is does not, this is incorrect.

Comment: It is correct. Look it up here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html Quote: "E > F Matches any F element that is a child of an element E."

Comment: @Connor - If you mean that the ID is `shape` rather than `#shape`, you could have just edited the answer and fixed the typo.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario No, i mean your answer is correct, this answer is incorrect. That selector does not select and div element that is a child of #shape

Comment: @Connor: You're mixing up **child** and **descendant**. While all children are descendants, not all descendants are children (of the  same parent).

Comment: It really depends on how you define **child**.

Comment: I do apologize  i thought, i class them as children, @mario is right, but your answer isn't very clear, as i class everything inside of a element as children

Comment: @Mario - Out of curiosity... What alternative definition of child do you have in mind?

Comment: No worries, you're actually right, based on interpretation. :) @ÁlvaroG.Vicario For me **children** are only those elements directly sitting inside an element. Real world analogy: Grandparents might call the children of their children children as well, but they're actually their grandchildren.

Comment: But for people that don't know what this selector is, this could be very confusing.

Comment: This information is incorrect. I do not understand the 4 votes here.

Answer (score 2):

this applies the styles to `div`s which are direct children of element with id `#shape`

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/25RLM/)

in the demo the style is not applied to `section > div` because the container `div` is not a direct child of `#shape`

Answer (score 1):

`>` is the child [combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators), also known as the direct descendant combinator.
That means the selector `#shape > div` only selects divs that sit directly inside a tag with ID `#shape`

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/JDs9G/